# SemanticZoom scrolling not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm having some trouble with implementing SemanticZoom. The SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView ItemsSource is bound to a CollectionViewSource in my ViewModel. The ZoomedOutView is also bound to the same CollectionViewSource but to CollectionViewSource.View.CollectionGroups.

When I start the app all is well and the information is displayed perfectly in both views. The only problem is that when I click on a group in ZoomedOutView the scroll bar doesn't move and stays on the first group. How can I make the scroll bar scroll to the selected group?

I tried itemsGridView.ScrollIntoView(...) via the ViewChangeStarted event but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems like this if you've been overriding Equals on the objects being bound to both GridViews.